# Accessing file stored in a Docker volume

Tags: docker

I was reading the following https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/06/common-dockerfile-mistakes/ and got caught up on a section:

> Volumes in your image are added when you run your
>   container, not when you build it. You should never interact with your
>   declared volume in your build process as it should only be used when
>   you run your container.
>
> Example: Creating a file in my build process and then running cat on
>   the file once the image is run works fine:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu:12.04
> RUN echo "Hello Charlie!" > /test.txt
>
> CMD ["cat", "/test.txt"]
>
> $ docker run test-build-volume
> Hello Charlie!
> ```
>
> If I attempt to do the same thing for a file stored in a volume then
>   it won't work:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu:12.04
> RUN echo "Hello Charlie!" > /var/data/test.txt
>
> CMD ["cat", "/var/data/test.txt"]
>
> $ docker run test-build-volume
> cat: can't open '/var/data/test.txt': No such file or directory
> ```

I don't see what is wrong with the second example? Is it incorrect (typo?). The only difference I see is `/test.txt` replaced with `/var/data/test.txt`, I fail to see the problem they should work the same? Is there something fundamental in Docker I'm missing?

Comment: Can you verify /var/data exists using docker exec -it  test-build-volume ls -l /var

Comment: Hi Karl, did you solve this?

Comment: @tgogos Hi! I just saw your answer, haven't had time. But I'll check your answer out :)

Answer (score 1):

[GSUgambit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749979/gsugambit) is right about `echo` silently failing, but (deleted the relative post).

IMHO the example is not verifiable, it lacks the details of how to [Start a container with a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume), doesn't make clear that `/var/data` doesn't exist at the time of build and that it is later created when you run a container (see case 1 below).

---

A few details which might help:

### Volumes, `Source`, `Destination` fields & 2 different cases:

When you `docker inspect` a container with a volume notice the two fields:

- `Source` (host location of files)
- `Destination` (container location of files)

for example:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "myvol2",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol2/_data",
        "Destination": "/app",
         ...
    }
],
```

#### Case 1: `destination` location doesn't exist

In this case, `docker run ...` with a volume option will create a new *destination* directory in the container, for example:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v test_volume:/this_folder_will_be_created ubuntu
root@6b80b9895dcc:/# cd /this_folder_will_be_created/
root@6b80b9895dcc:/this_folder_will_be_created#
```

#### Case 2: `destination` location exists

> #### [Populate a volume using a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container)
>
> If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as `/app/` above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume.

Answer (score 0):

/var/data does not exists.
Your docker build must be giving this warning.

Try replace /var/data with /var/log
This will work.